# Input values aren't lining up with label values

Tags: html, css, forms

Here is the HTML and associated CSS.  Can anyone pin point what I'm doing wrong? The input text boxes are appearing below their corresponding labels.

```
form label.blockLabel {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
}

form fieldset#contactFields input {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 140px;
}
```

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="POST" action="mailto:eric.franklin@ucdenver.edu">
<p>* indicates a required field</p>

<fieldset id="contactFields">
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>                        
        <label class="blockLabel" for="fName">First Name<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" required="required" />                           
        <label class="blockLabel" for="lName">Last Name<span>*</span></label> 
            <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" required="required" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="email">Email Address<span>*</span></label>   
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="street">Street Address</label>   
            <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="city">City</label>   
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="Denver" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="state">State</label>     
            <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="CO" maxlength="2" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="zip">Zip</label> 
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" maxlength="10" />
        <label class="blockLabel" for="phone">Phone</label> 
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />                             
</fieldset>
```

Comment: In this code everything is ok. http://jsfiddle.net/om9wd6ef/. Probably you have display block on something.

Comment: That works, but I'm going for the Labels on the left and the corresponding Inputs on the right, in line with the Labels.

Comment: I edited your question so it has correct indention. When asking a question, please make sure the code indented correctly so it is easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle.  I think you just needed to remove the

```
form fieldset
```

selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/cL6jm2r4/

Comment: If you want them to align on the left, just remove the margin:

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/cL6jm2r4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fieldset id="contactFields">
                <legend>Contact Information</legend>                        
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="fName">First Name<span>*</span> : 
                        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" required="required" />  </label>                         
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="lName">Last Name<span>*</span> : 
                        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" required="required" /></label> 
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="email">Email Address<span>*</span>  :
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" /></label> 
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="street">Street Address   : 
                        <input type="text" id="street" name="street" /></label> 
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="city">City : 
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="Denver" /></label>   
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="state">State    : 
                        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="CO" maxlength="2" /></label>  
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="zip">Zip : 
                        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" maxlength="10" /></label> 
                    <label class="blockLabel" for="phone">Phone :
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" /> </label>                             
            </fieldset> 











<style>
  .blockLabel {
        display: block;
    margin-left: 140px;
    }

    form fieldset #contactFields input {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 140px;
    }
</style>
```